# Defining a del operator

Tags: vector, variable-definitions, vector-calculus, operators

I understand the `Grad` function is a mean to taking the gradient of an arbitrary function.

However, I'd like to define the `Del` operator and I did so by

```
∇[x_, y_, z_] := {(∂/∂x), (∂/∂y), (∂/∂z)}
```

Unfortunately, this vector function isn't working.

Any help is appreciated.